React native expo web view component is not opening pop-up web pages
I am trying to use a payment gateway in my React native app, and I am using the WebView component to render the payment gateway inside my app. In my regular browser, along with the process of payment, a pop-up web page is shown for OTP confirmation, the issue with the WebView in my app is that it's not opening this pop-up web page.
Here is my compoent:
<WebView
    source={{uri:paymentUrl}}
    onNavigationStateChange={handleNavigationChange}
    style={{height:Dimensions.get('screen').height/9.5, width:'100%'}}
/>

Here is the onNavigationStateChange function (It's not working, so returning nothing when the pop-up message is supposed to open):
    const handleNavigationChange = navState => {
        const {url} = navState;
        // Handle navigation changes such as pop-ups or redirects here
        if (url.includes('otp-confirmation')) {
          // Example of handling OTP confirmation
          Alert.alert('OTP Confirmation', 'Handling OTP confirmation here.');
        }
        if(navState.url.split('/')[4] === 'furl'){
            setPaymentUrl('');
            setSnackbarMessage('Payment Failed, Please Try Again.');
            setVisible(true);
        }else if(navState.url.split('/')[4] === 'surl'){
            submitHandler();
            setPaymentUrl('');
            setSnackbarMessage('Paid Successfully!');
            setVisible(true);
        }else if(navState.url.includes('otp-page-url')){
            setWebViewUrl(navState.url);
        }
    };

I tried the onNavigationStateChange for an attempt to catch this pop-up web page link and open it in another WebView, but there is absolutely no response for an attempt to open another page.

I believe the event you are looking for is onOpenWindow but you may want to take a look at javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically and setSupportMultipleWindows
<WebView
  ...
  javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically={true}
  onOpenWindow={(syntheticEvent) => {
    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
    const { targetUrl } = nativeEvent
    console.log('Intercepted OpenWindow for', targetUrl)
    console.log(nativeEvent);
  }}
  setSupportMultipleWindows={true}
/>

You will either need to create a new Webview to simulate a popup or follow the URL in the current webview.
I hope this helps!
